# By copy-by-value, create a 2-D list of duplicate elements without for-loops in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, copy, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I want to generate

```
[[0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0]]
```

, where all elements are independent values, not related by references.

Although it can be achieved by

```
P = []
for i in range(3):
    P.append([0] * 3)
```

Still hoping it can be done **without using any for-loops**.

I tried `P = [[-1] * 3] * 3`.
However, the three `[0, 0, 0]` are actually referring to the same object. A reassignment `P[0][0] = 1` leads to

```
[[1, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0]]
```

instead of the desired result

```
[[1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0]]
```

So, is there any way to do it in an one-line style without for-loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you *probably* did not mean to exclude using `for` loops inside list comprehensions, but here is an answer without the word *for* (because ... you can?)

```
x = list(map(lambda p: [0]*3, [None]*3))
```

Comment: XD  I _did_ mean to exclude the `for`. I just want learn more about the possibility about Python by not using `for`, not for any practical reasons. Anyway, your answer introduces `list()`, `map()`, and anonymous function `lambda` to me, which makes me learn more. Thank you very much~!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a list comprehension:

```
P = [[0] * 3 for _ in range(3)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I learn some new stuff! Cool! However, may I ask for some ways without `for`? Or, maybe, the `for` here is not really a for-loop?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It is educative and practical.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [`numpy`](https://www.numpy.org/),

```
import numpy as np    
array = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=int)
array[0][0] = 1
```

Comment: why are you using `zeros_like` here and unnecessarily creating *two* arrays? Using `.zeros` makes much more sense and if you *really* want it as ints then use `astype`.

Comment: couldn't grasp that before, corrected now, thanks for the feedback. @modesitt

Comment: Thank you!!  `ndarray` is also a great option.